# Windows Phone 8.1 Photos app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Which file/image date property is the default Windows Phone 8.1 Photos app using to sort and group the photos?

In the app I am working on I am saving a jpg to KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary. The saved jpg is always grouped under "older photos" and it doesn't have a date displayed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can access date from StorageFile in PictureLibrary. Using the date you can sort and group as default app.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Pallam. however, I think you misunderstood my question. I was asking about the default Photos app on the phone. I'm not looking to sort the photos in my app.